# How to render data on UI using knockout 3.0 and later versions

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am using knockout JS to render data from DB to the UI. I know that in knockout  version 2 and earlier, you could do something like this:

```
<div class="container" data-bind="load: loadData()">
```

The load property is totally made up because in knockout.js you can’t just call functions as they are. You need to have a property where you can call it.

Now, this way of binding is no longer supported in knockout 3 and later. So, does anyone know an alternative way?

**UI**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='knockout-3.1.0.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container" data-bind="load: loadData()">
  <table data-bind="visible: people().length > 0" class="students">
      <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>Remove</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody data-bind="foreach: people">
          <tr>
                  <td>
                    <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
                </td>

              </td>
              <td>
                 <span data-bind="text: age"></span>
              </td>
              <td class="buttons">
                <button >Edit</button>
                <button >Delete</button>
            </td>         
          </tr>
</tbody>
</script></tbody>
  </table>  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
var personModel = function(id, name, age){
  var self = this;  
  self.id = ko.observable(id); 
  self.name = ko.protectedObservable(name);
  self.age = ko.protectedObservable(age);     
};


var model = function () {
    var self = this;
    this.person_name = ko.observable("");
    this.person_age = ko.observable("");
    this.people = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.selectedPerson = ko.observable();

        self.loadData = function () {
        //1) RETRIEVE STUDENT INFO
         //fetch existing student data from database 
          $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url : 'refresher_save.php',
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(data){ //json string of the student records returned from the server             
                  for(var x in data){
                      //student details
                      var id = data[x]['id'];
                      var name = data[x]['name'];
                      var age = data[x]['age'];
                      //add student record to observable array 
                      self.people.push(new personModel(id, name, age));

                  }               
              }
          });
};
```

Comment: It sounds like you want a data fetching operation to be kicked off at startup? I think you want a custom binding, and do your data fetch in its init component. A nice writeup on custom bindings: http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/07/another-look-at-custom-bindings-for.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just explicitly call loadData in model, like this.

```
var personModel = function(id, name, age){
    var self = this;  
    self.id = ko.observable(id); 
    self.name = ko.protectedObservable(name);
    self.age = ko.protectedObservable(age);     
};


var model = function () {
    var self = this;
    this.person_name = ko.observable("");
    this.person_age = ko.observable("");
    this.people = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.selectedPerson = ko.observable();

    self.loadData = function () {
        //1) RETRIEVE STUDENT INFO
        //fetch existing student data from database 
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'refresher_save.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) { //json string of the student records returned from the server             
                for (var x in data) {
                    //student details
                    var id = data[x]['id'];
                    var name = data[x]['name'];
                    var age = data[x]['age'];
                    //add student record to observable array 
                    self.people.push(new personModel(id, name, age));

                }
            }
        });
    };

    self.loadData();
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(new model());
});
```

Your HTML was also not formed correctly, this should be better. I removed an extra `</td>` and `</script></tbody>`

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='knockout-3.1.0.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container" data-bind="load: loadData()">
        <table data-bind="visible: people().length > 0" class="students">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Remove</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: people">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <span data-bind="text: age"></span>
                    </td>
                    <td class="buttons">
                        <button>Edit</button>
                        <button>Delete</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mhh tried that.. gives me this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "foreach: function (){return people }"
Message: people is not defined

Comment: Are you calling `ko.applyBindings(new model());` anywhere?